# Sending notification to parse app through my localhost

Tags: php, android, api, parsing

Its my very first time in android and I'm making an application to receive notification and configured with parse notification.
Notifications are delivering successfully from their push notification portal.
I want to make it through my server.
Requirements are

- I want to send notifications to all devices app installed on.
- I want no expiry time.

I tried codes from google and stackoverflow but none of them delivered notification to my device, I'm trying this from localhost, so is there any need of being it on server like sending email needs it?

A good simple code is expected. Thank you guys :)